# Error after upgrading datastax to version 5

Tags: cassandra

After upgrading to DataStax Enterprise version 5, the node does not come up, and I get this error in the log:

> Insufficient permissions on directory /hints

Where is this directory located?

Answer (score 2):

> Insufficient permissions on directory /hints

I'm guessing that your "cassandra" user doesn't have permissions to add a new directory on its own.  Similar to the tarball installation process, you'll need to create the directory yourself.

> where the location for this directory?

By default, the location for /hints is:

```
$CASSANDRA_HOME/data/hints
```

You can also override this in your cassandra.yaml, with the `hints_directory` property:

```
hints_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/hints
```